# double space line in the txt file

Tags: java

im working on  a code where i prompt the user for a name of a file and then output the file s a double-space.

this is the txt that i have in my txt file:

Twas brilling and the slithy toves
did gyre and gimble in the wabe. 
All mimsey were the borogroves, 
and the mome raths outgrabe.
 my code works ok .. it prints out the txt with a double-space. ... 
my question is how can i print the original txt aswell?

```
enter code here

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Doublespace{
    public static void main (String [] args )
    throws FileNotFoundException{
 Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("enter the name of the file ");
 String words = console.nextLine();


        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File (words));



        PrintStream output = new PrintStream( new File ( "wordstxt2.txt"));

        while (input.hasNextLine () ){
            words= input.nextLine();
            doubleSpace (words, output);
            System.out.println();
            doubleSpace (words, System.out);
        }
    }




        public static void doubleSpace( String words , PrintStream output){
            Scanner input = new Scanner (words);
            if (input.hasNext()){
                output.print(input.next());
                while (input.hasNext()){
                output.print(" " +input.next());

}

            }
            output.println();
        }
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an `ArrayList` to store the original text file and the altered one.

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
    String str;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
        list.add(str);
    }

    String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```